# Input Source Only Recognize Last Index in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, inputstream

i Have an array list that contain path :

```
private ArrayList<String> theFile = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> listFileFolder(File folder){
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        listFileFolder(fileEntry);
    } else {
        String save = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
        theFile.add(save);
      }
    }   
    return this.theFile;
 }
```

so after i successfully getting the list of absolute path in my directory, i use this path for my input. here it is my code that use that absolute path

```
       ArrayList<String> theFile = new ArrayList<String>();
       File theDirectory = new File("G:\\XMLCode");
       theFile = mp.listFileFolder(theDirectory);
        for(int k = 0;k<theFile.size();k++){
            System.out.println(theFile.get(k).toString());
            direktory = theFile.get(k).toString();
            xr.parse(direktory);
        }
```

so what i expected from above the code , everytime the loop goes on it will output the file from the directory, so it will parse the directory from index 0,1,2 (depend how much file in the directory, in this case the directory G:\XMLCode contain 3 file) 
but when i run the code , the output always the last index in this case (2) 
here it is the result from my `System.out.println(theFile.get(k).toString())`

```
G:\XMLCode\Lifeline1.xml
G:\XMLCode\Lifeline2.xml
G:\XMLCode\menuUI.xml
```

but when i want to put in the path in my function `xr.parse(direktory);` it only take the last index which is `G:\XMLCode\menuUI.xml`.

thanks for your help, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So if your `System.out.println(theFile.get(k).toString());` prints the correct path but your string `direktory = theFile.get(k).toString();` is different, how can that be?? Have you used a debugger to follow your loop, that's always a good idea if you have weird results like this. Also you can use a simple for-each loop in that case, instead of you for-loop with the `direktory` variable you can use `for(String direktory : theFile) ...`.

Comment: @xander hi sir thanks for the responses ! , yes ! i have tried use a debugger to follow the loop , in the loop the value direktory have no problem. from my point of view, i think the problem came from xr.parse function because everytime i call  `theFile.get(k).toString()` it only processed the last value of the arrayList value, i still have no idea why because i use xr.parse from XML parser from `XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()`.